# Getting final status for radio button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have activity which have some radio button groups , i want to get final status of this radio group and add the radio id in the list of type integer .

but my problem when choosing option 1 and then option 2 i getting this to radio id's in the list ! but i want to store only the last statues when user move to another activity

I'm trying to use Ondestroy()

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup04);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId){
                case R.id.RadioButton11:

                    BatteryActivity.this.Answer = 23 ;

                break;

                case R.id.RadioButton08:
                    BatteryActivity.this.Answer = 24 ;

                break;
            }//


        }
    });


}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    ((MyApplication) BatteryActivity.this.getApplication()).setAnswerList(this.Answer);
    ((MyApplication) BatteryActivity.this.getApplication()).setSectionList(10);
}
```

Comment: instead of `onDestroy()` use `onStop()`.

Comment: Can't understand why you need to store only when the user change activitys, you can just update a global var for that

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your onStop() method. Remove rediogroup's checkchangedListener method and onDestroy() method...

```
int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton); // ID of selected radiobutton

switch(idx ){
     case R.id.RadioButton11:

           BatteryActivity.this.Answer = 23 ;

           break;

     case R.id.RadioButton08:
           BatteryActivity.this.Answer = 24 ;

           break;
     }
```